# tikzmark: how to debug?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not sure why, but on a big document that takes several minutes to compile, I have a compilation error involving a tikzmark that does not exists (only after the second compilation), but I don't manage to reproduce this error on a smaller document for now.

However, I don't understand why, as this tikzmark should be present (this is even more true as it compiles the first time). I tried to search in aux and log files if I could find the name of a tikzmark, but it seems that none of them are written here. I thought that tikzmark would get written into an aux file as I need to compile multiple time for them to work, so why can't I see anything? Where are tikzmark stored? Is there any tool I can use to debug tikzmark?

Comment: You can always make a Minimal Working Example. Start by copying the problematic document. -then clean it for *all* unneeded stuff. Move `\end{document}` halfway up the document and recompile - keep deleting until *everything* except what is causing the error is gone.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do that... but it takes quite some time to do as the document takes several minutes to compile ^^ But my question is actually generic and not related only to my specific problem.

Comment: Try to externalize the tikz graphics into seperate files thus making compilation process quicker. `\usetikzlibrary{external}`

Comment: You debug this like any other TeX error. Personally I would start by adding `\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen` to the preamble to get the full error backtrace and hope that I see something suspicious in there. Then I might add `\tracingall` as close as possible to where the error occurs to gain more insight into the expansion flow. If I still can't pinpoint the error, I bisect the entire document like suggested in the other comment and construct a MWE. Rinse and repeat until I find the the cause of the problem.

Comment: tikzmarks are stored in the aux. But if you get an error involving a missing tikzmark then it is not so surprising that you don't find it there.  So the more interesting question is how you call the tikzmark as normally a missing tikzmark is handled fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh you are right, they are in the aux... So that's really weird, because none of them are printed (I would tought some of them are)... Let's continue the investigation!

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh thanks, I didn't knew these commands! Also, one problem is that the line of the error is not matching with any input file (I include these files using `subfiles`) so I'm not even sure which file produces the error. And bisecting is long.

Comment: @tush Thanks, the problem is that I'm using a tikzcd-derived library, and tikzcd can't externalize stuff (I'd love to fix that issue btw, but it's another question).

Comment: The thing to look for in the aux file is `\savepointas`.  If you have any thoughts on how to make debugging easier with tikzmarks, please do let me know.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Ok thanks for the precision, I guess it's hard to make something better... (btw, is `pdfsavepos` better than `tikzmark` if I don't want to add additional space?) So I'm trying to slowly bisect but it's really weird (and therefore hard). Basically, if I include files A, B, C, D, it compiles. If I include files A, B, C, D, E, it fails. If I include E alone it succeeds, if I include A, B, C, E it succeeds... I'm starting to wonder if there is a maximum number of page and/or tikzmark that can be handled correctly... Does it ring a bell by any chance?

Comment: The tikz positioning mechanism uses pdfsavepos deep down (as do all the alternatives, I believe).  Tikzmark is essentially a tikz-wrapper around it.  The library also provides `\pgfmark` for when the box that tikzmark inserts would be inconvenient.  I've not encountered a maximum for the number of tikzmarks, can you tell me how many there are in each file?  Are you sure there aren't any duplicates - if there are then you could use the prefixing mechanism to make them unique when including each file without needing to change them in the files.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Ok, thanks a lot! So I finally solved the issue after a night of fight: one lines was not necessary, and it was creating a bug in a very subtle and rare case (and the bug depends on the way the file is compiled: I was able to compile fine from a project with the appropriate aux file obtained by adding gradually new tikzmarks, but cleaning the aux file and rebuilding would just break everything). Anyway, thanks everybody, and sorry for the noise!

Comment: Don't be "sorry for the noise" - if you have a difficulty with a TeX/LaTeX document then that's what this site is for.  On occasion, the act of asking helps the asker figure out the problem for themselves, but that's absolutely fine!  And please do let me know if you have any suggestions for how to improve tikzmark - the github repository is at https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark